# SaltStack - iptables icmp rule doesn't work

Tags: iptables, saltstack

System:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
salt-master 2016.3.3 (Boron)
salt-minion 2016.3.3 (Boron)
```

Trying to add an icmp rule will result in an error message.

**init.sls**

```
INPUT:
  iptables.chain_present:
    - table: filter
    - family: ipv4

icmp:
  iptables.insert:
    - table: filter
    - chain: INPUT
    - jump: ACCEPT
    - proto: icmp
    - position: 1
    - save: True
    - require:
      - iptables: INPUT
```

Error Message:

```
ID: icmp
Function: iptables.insert
Result:   False
Comment:  Failed to set iptables rule for icmp.
          Attempted rule was /sbin/iptables -t filter -I INPUT 1 -p icmp -m icmp --jump ACCEPT
```

I also tried following:

```
icmp:
  iptables.append:
    - table: filter
    - chain: INPUT
    - jump: ACCEPT
    - proto: icmp
    - save: True
```

... but it's the same:

```
ID:       icmp
Function: iptables.append
Result:   False
Comment:  Failed to set iptables rule for icmp.
          Attempted rule was /sbin/iptables -t filter -A INPUT  -p icmp -m icmp --jump ACCEPT for ipv4
```

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Did you try to execute the command `iptables -t filter -A INPUT  -p icmp -m icmp --jump ACCEPT` directly? It should help you find what the error is.

Comment: Yeah, i tried this command and it works as expected.  The firewall rule is append.

Comment: Do you run salt-minion as root?

Comment: I run it as root, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the problematic minions and this solves the problem.

And additionally on one of the minions there was an older saltstack version which causes the problem.